# How to scrape data without overloading the server?

Tags: php, csv, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm trying to build a script to scrape specific data form a website. The script is using the website searching api. The search result gives pages of results each page has about 20 post then I have to go deep in each post and extract the data. This cause the data to through a `500 Internal Server Error`. I think that this is the result of overloading the server because sometimes it has to search about 400 pages.

I tried to refresh the page every specific number of results and save the data in a `CSV` file but it stops after about 10 pages.

Is there a solution for that?

Comment: [`sleep`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.sleep.php) between requests.

Comment: The page refreshes itself using JavaScript so what is better, to sleep before the next request or in the end of the current one?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at error_log, normally 500 errors are logged there so it can give you a clue